# Polymorphism, Calling child method of parent

Tags: c#, inheritance, unity-game-engine, polymorphism

Hi everyone I am programming in Unity3d with C# and while I was writing my code I stumbled with a little issue, I write to you an example because I dont know explain me.

```
class Base
{
    public string name;
}
class Derived : Base
{
    public void Gun();
}

class BasePlayer
{
    public Base x;
}

class SoldierPlayer : BasePlayer
{ 

}
```

The situation is this, I want to do something like that

```
SoldierPlayer.x.Gun();
```

But I don't know how do it

The real case is this

```
 public class BasePlayerController : MonoBehaviour
        {

            public BasePlayerManager playerManager; 
...
public class RobotPlayerController : BasePlayerController {
...
playerManager = gameObject.AddComponent<RobotPlayerManager>();
```

And I will use new methods

**UPDATE 1**

I did a example better, I want to do in Base Controller manager.user.energy and be treated as the next type RobotManager.RobotUser.energy

```
BaseController
BaseManager
BaseUser

class BaseController
{
    BaseManager manager;
    public virtual void Move(int x,int y)...
}

class BaseManager {
    BaseUser user;
    public virtual Pause(bool state);
}

class BaseUser {
    int life
}

RobotController
RobotManager
RobotUser

class RobotController : BaseController
{
    // manager as RobotManager?
    public void Ray(int x,int y);
}

class RobotManager : BaseManager
{
    // user as RobotUser?
}

class RobotUser : BaseUser 
{
    int energy;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**
I seek to do this

```
public Run()
{
    RobotController rc = new RobotController();
    rc.manager.energy;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you inherit in your `SoldierPlayer` from `Base`?  If you wanna do this, in your `BasePlayer` it should've a field like this `public Derived x;`. I strongly suggest you, that you've a look at [Polymorphismus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms173152.aspx).

Comment: You are looking for *abstract classes and methods* and for *virtual methods*. Google that first.

Comment: Shouldn't simply `x` be of type `Derived`?

Comment: Base and Derived is other class , I know use virtual method but this case I pose I don't know, @Sinatr I can't because I am inheriting from a Core class.

Comment: @ChristophKn has a comment and his comment is actually the answer to your question. `public Base x;` should be `public Derived x;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call `SoldierPlayer.x.Gun();` because `SoldierPlayer.x` has type `Base` which has not method Gun(). OOP world and C# can provide you many solutions, your choose depends on your goals.

some of them (order by best practise):

1) **Overriding Polymorphism**.  Add .*Gun()* method to *Base* class and implemend it in derived classes. For example

```
class Base
{
    public string name;
    public void virtual Gun()
    {
        Trace.Log("I'm base class, i can't do anything");
    }
}
class Derived : Base
{
    public override void Gun()
    {
        Consule.WriteLine("Hello i have gun");
    }
}

class Derived2 : Base
{
    public override void Gun()
    {
        Consule.WriteLine("Hello i have 2 guns");
    }
}
```

2) **Overloading Polymorphism** In many source this method is mentioned like some kind of polymorphism AD-HOC

```
public void GunAction(Derived2 o)
{
    o.Gun();
}
public void GunAction(Derived1 o)
{
    o.Gun();
}
public void GunAction(Base o)
{
    Trace.Log("I'm base class, i can't do anything");
}
```

3) **is-cast**

```
public void GunAction(Base o)
{
    if(o is Derived1 )
        o.Gun();
    if(o is Derived2 )
        o.Gun();
}
```

**UPDATE 1** answering to your new requirements

```
class BaseController
{
    public BaseManager manager;
...

class RobotController1 : BaseController
{
    // manager as RobotManager? - no it is stil BaseManager
    public void Ray(int x,int y);
}


class RobotController2 : BaseController
{
    // manager as RobotManager? - yes. now it is RobotManager 
    public void Ray(int x,int y);

    public RobotController2()
    {
        manager = new RobotManager();
    }
}

public void Run()
{
    var controller = new RobotController2();// you have RobotManager 
    controller.manager = new BaseManager();// it is again BaseManager
}
```

Comment: For option one you should make the method `virtual` in the base and `override` it in the derived class.  And you need to explain the other options.

Comment: I just provided an exmple. I show you how to fix such situation for manager member. You should do the same job with user member

Comment: I did that , can you see my second Update?

Comment: @Xafi, just read a bit about this whole topic, you're missing some basic abstraction.